# Show the Bloch equation for spin $1/2$ particle in magnetic field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-spin

I must show that if we have a particle with spin $1/2$, mass $m_{e}$, and charge $-e$ in a constant magnetic field $\vec{B}$, then:

$$ \frac{d\vec{S}}{dt}=\frac{-e}{m_{e}}\vec{S}\times \vec{B}$$

I have been thinking about this exercise for several days and currently have no idea. Any suggestions on how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

The ingredients that you need are the following:

- The commutation relations of angular momentum:
  $$[S_x,S_y]=i\hbar S_z $$ (same for cyclical pertutations {y,z,x} and {z,x,y})
- how operators evolve in Heisenberg picture, for a given operator $O$, we have
  $$i\hbar \frac{dO}{dt}=[O,H]$$
  where [] is the commutator and $H$ is the Hamiltonian
- The Hamiltonian of a magnetic moment $\boldsymbol\mu $ interacting with a magnetic field is
  $$H=-\boldsymbol \mu \cdot \mathbf B$$

with this and a bit of insight on the intrinsic properties of the electron, you should be able to derive the relation that you are looking for.